# Trying to implement bundle classes for a custom content type

Tags: entities

I've got a custom content type (generated by drush) that extends ContentEntityBase and a bundle class (also generated by drush) that extends my content type.  I've registered my bundle with hook_entity_bundle_info() in my_module.module, and the entity type bundle service shows my bundle belonging to my content type:

```
    >>> $bundleInfo = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')
=> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeBundleInfo {#1475
     +"_serviceId": "entity_type.bundle.info",
   }

>>> $bundles = $bundleInfo->getBundleInfo('my_content_type')
=> [
     "my_content_type" => [],
     "dc_thing" => [
       "label" => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup {#5566},
       "class" => "Drupal\my_module\Entity\Bundle\DcThing",
     ],
   ]
```

But when I try creating an entity using my dc_thing bundle, Drupal complains that my content type is missing a bundle

```
 >>> $etm = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')
=> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager {#996
     +"_serviceId": "entity_type.manager",
   }

>>> $thing = $etm->getStorage('my_content_type')->create(['type' => 'dc_thing', 'label' => 'Particle Mang'])
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException with message 'Missing bundle for entity type my_content_type'
```

All of the example code I've been able to find for bundle classes extend Node, but as far as I'm aware, the only bundles for Node in core are for Article and Basic Page, I don't see where there's a bundle defined for the Node entity type.

```
>>> $article = $etm->getStorage('node')->create(['type' => 'article', 'label' => 'test article'])
```

works just fine.

Comment: Normally you have a config entity for the bundles of a content entity and for each bundle you create a bundle config entry. In theory it should be possible to define bundles in code, but this never worked in the past and I'm not sure if this has changed with the introduction of bundle classes.

Comment: Bundle classes are a new feature introduced in 9.3.  https://www.drupal.org/node/3191609  Unless I'm completely misunderstanding, it really looks like this would let us get around having to use the UI to create content types.

Comment: If you don't want to use the UI you can put them in the module /config/install folder like core is providing the node content types in the standard profile: /core/profiles/standard/config/install/node.type.article.yml

Comment: After introduction of bundle classes I tried to create bundles by code. But seems that is not working. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/omdb_api/-/blob/1.x-dev/src/Entity/Bundle/Movie.php

Comment: @miststudent2011 Did you register your bundle in hook_entity_bundle_info()?

Comment: Yes, I have https://git.drupalcode.org/project/omdb_api/-/blob/1.x-dev/omdb_api.module#L98

Comment: @miststudent2011 Try putting that in hook_entity_bundle_info() instead of hook_entity_bundle_info_alter(), without the if statements.  That alter hook is for modifying/adding bundles to existing content types.  I got caught on that one when I was starting my type, too.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in my create params and content entity annotation.

In my entity_keys annotation, I had  `"bundle" = "bundle",`

Changing `'type' => 'dc_thing'` to `'bundle' => 'dc_thing'` got me unstuck.  Then changing my annotation to `"bundle" = "type",` got things working as expected (passing my bundle as `type` in my create statement.

Big ups to John Pitcairn on d.o.