# What is the use case for "bundle fields" that are independent of an entity type's base fields?

Tags: entities, 9

So I can define a custom entity in code (quickstart: `drush generate entity:content`).

I can then use [BaseFieldDefinition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21BaseFieldDefinition.php/class/BaseFieldDefinition/9.4.x) to define base fields that will be shared by all entities of that type.

However, if my entity has bundles, I may want to define some fields only for certain bundles.  It seems this is sometimes called a "bundle field" on drupal.org, and they can be defined in [hook_entity_bundle_field_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_bundle_field_info/9.4.x), but they:

> need to provide a field storage definition via
> hook_entity_field_storage_info() unless they are computed.

As noted in the docs [this API is not yet finalized.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2346347)

Could someone please explain why I might want to define a "bundle field" using `hook_entity_bundle_field_info()` and `hook_entity_field_storage_info()` together instead of using the Field UI to add fields to bundles?  Is there any performance benefit to doing it this way, or is this approach strictly for module developers to add fields to entity bundles that they are shipping with the modules?

Comment: You can ship config with modules as well.

Comment: @4uk4 isnt the whole point of bundle class and bundle fields is to eliminate shipping of config in module?

Comment: I believe bundle claases are not mature enough to replace shipping of config as I can not find single instance where it worked for custom entity, you can observe same on CR as well https://www.drupal.org/node/3191609

Comment: Related https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/312015/71454